# ¿Cómo cambiar de una activity a otra usando el BottonNavigationActivity?

Tags: java, android-studio

Lo que ocurre es que tengo tres activity y he intentado de muchas formas hacer que el botón del menú cambie a la otra activity pero no pasa absolutamente nada. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_search:
                Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_user:
                Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
                startActivity(c);
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Hola, muestra lo que intentaste y te ayudaremos a encontrar el error.

Comment: Hola, lo que podria decir es que mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener no se lo estas asignando a nadie.

Comment: Tu código parece estar casi bien **tal y como lo tienes**, excepto que debes quitar el `return false;` que tienes al final fuera del bloque `switch` y poner en su lugar `return true;`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas definiendo el listener `mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` , pero no lo estas asignando al `BotonNavigationView`

Tienes que obtener la referencia de tu `BotonNavigationView`, por ejemplo si su id es `bottom_navigation` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        ...
        ... />
```

Obten su referencia:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
```

ahora usa `bottomNavigationView` para definir el listener:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_search:
                Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_user:
                Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
                startActivity(c);
                break;

        }
      return true;
     }
  });
```

---

en el caso de tu código original puedes definir el listener que creaste:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

de esta forma obtendrás lo deseado al dar clic.